# Unable to trigger modal from within jQuery DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I have a generic modal just before the closing body tag of my page. I use Javascript to show the modal when a button is clicked, passing data attribute values embedded within the button to the modal title, body and footer. This makes the modal dynamic. It works great, however, when I add the trigger button within jQuery DataTable, it fails to trigger the modal.

This is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_confirm_action" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <div class="pull-right m-l-15">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm modal_close_btn" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" title="Close"> &times;</button>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.modal-header-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--render data via JS-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" role="button" id="action_url"> Yes, Continue </a>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"> No, Cancel </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the button that triggers it:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white modal_trigger_confirm_action" data-title="Delete Post" data-msg="Sure to delete?" data-url="'.base_url('posts/delete_post/'.$id).'">Delete</a>
```

Note: I'm using server side processing with DataTables (and CodeIgniter), so the button above is inside my controller method, and rendered in one column, like this:

```
...
$row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white modal_trigger_confirm_action" data-title="Delete Post" data-msg="Sure to delete?" data-url="'.base_url('posts/delete_post/'.$post_id).'">Delete</a>';
...
```

This is the JavaScript that opens the modal:

```
$('.modal_trigger_confirm_action').click(function() {
    //get data value params
    var title = $(this).data('title'); 
    var msg = $(this).data('msg'); 
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $('#modal_confirm_action .modal-title').text(title); //dynamic title
    $('#modal_confirm_action .modal-body').html(msg); //dynamic body content
    $('#modal_confirm_action .modal-footer #action_url').attr('href', url); //url to delete item
    $('#modal_confirm_action').modal('show'); //show the modal
});
```

Clicking the Delete button within each row doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the button is generated dynamically and not the part of DOM when it loaded first time so you need to trigger click on that dynamically generated button something like this.

```
$(document).on( "click",".modal_trigger_confirm_action", function() { //logic here });
```

Comment: You're life saver @Ravi! I would never have figured this out myself. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$( ".modal_trigger_confirm_action" ).on( "click", function() {
  // your logic here
});
```

Comment: I really don't know the difference between using .click() and .on("click"), but I have done it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `.on("click")` is used to attached the event handler with elements, when elements are being created from script.
Here you can try I would like you to try this:

`$(document).on('click', '.modal_trigger_confirm_action', function(){
    // here your code.
});`

Comment: Thanks Pintu. This would have worked, Ravi's answer did the trick.

Comment: I would recommend you to  return only json data rather than html and parse them on front-end.